# GLib regex match gives segmentation fault on specific matches and patterns

Tags: c++, regex, glib

In my program, I scan files for certain text. After weeks of debugging I found out that certain lines of text in files give a segmentation fault depending on the regex pattern used. For example, I found the following line of text causes a segmentation fault

```
#include <glib.h>

int main()
{
    GRegex* regex = g_regex_new("\\bhtml\\b", G_REGEX_CASELESS, G_REGEX_MATCH_NOTEMPTY, NULL);
    //The following line causes a segmentation fault
    g_regex_match(regex, "<code>USR1</code>) f\374hren. Ersteres ist ein schwerer Fehler,", G_REGEX_MATCH_NOTEMPTY, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas the following which uses a different pattern **does not** cause a segmentation fault

```
#include <glib.h>

int main()
{
    GRegex* regex = g_regex_new("html", G_REGEX_CASELESS, G_REGEX_MATCH_NOTEMPTY, NULL);
    g_regex_match(regex, "<code>USR1</code>) f\374hren. Ersteres ist ein schwerer Fehler,", G_REGEX_MATCH_NOTEMPTY, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It is the combination of the regex pattern and the **\374** in the string that causes the segmentation fault. I noticed however that if I manually escape **\374** with **\\374**, no segmentation fault happens.

The source of that line of text comes from the file: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/stopping.html

For this specific case, when I read this file and store the line of text in a string, it gets stored in a string as **\374** instead of getting stored as **ü**.

How can I fix this problem such as if I were to be reading thousands of files with hundreds of lines in them which could contain anything, I can use any regex pattern and avoid segmentation faults caused by this?

Comment: Can't you just use `g_strescape` on the source string before evaluating it with `g_regex_match`?

Comment: Yes. It works with that. Found out about 15 minutes after asking this question -.- Though if you write the answer I'll mark it as answer. I feel bad asking many questions and then answering myself after I keep trying for days or minutes after asking the question. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've written an answer. I've had this "embarrassment" you've encountered a couple of times myself, but I wrote an answer anyway, since it might be useful for others. As long as it doesn't happen too often ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[g_strescape](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strescape) helps in such cases, because it simply escapes '\' (and other special characters), which will prevent `g_regex_match` from segfaulting.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the crash: it’s because the `GRegex` methods don’t accept invalid UTF-8 input. This is documented in the [introduction to `GRegex`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html#glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.description), but [could be documented more obviously](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748620).

`\374` is not valid UTF-8. The proper fix here is to convert from whatever input character encoding you have, to UTF-8, using (for example) [`g_locale_to_utf8()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-locale-to-utf8) or [`g_convert()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-convert). GLib only accepts UTF-8 encoded strings for all of its functions (unless documented otherwise), so you will likely run into problems like this again unless you convert or [validate](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-validate) all your strings on input.